# HTML to PDF using PDFkit in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, pdfkit

I am using PDFkit to convert my HTML page to PDF but it works not at all good.

My routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                           Controller#Action

                      root GET  /(:locale)(.:format)                  energycalcmod#front_end {:locale=>/en|de/}
   energycalcmod_front_end GET  /energycalcmod/front_end(.:format)    energycalcmod#front_end
                     embed GET  /embed(.:format)                      energycalcmod#embed
  energycalcmod_get_values POST /energycalcmod/get_values(.:format)   energycalcmod#get_values
```

I installed:

```
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'unicorn
```

Unicorn according to [this](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit).

The application looks like the picture under. When clicking in calculate it shows plots and results.

I would like to print the results in PDF, but when doing `http://localhost:8080/en.pdf` it shows only as PDF the initial route (i.e. it prints the picture under and not the calculations).

I watched this [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit?autoplay=true) from Ryan as well  but I do not what I am missing.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: When you just add .pdf in the end of the url if performs the standard get request, losing all the data - so like the first time you visit the page.

Comment: Thxs for your answer, that's a good inside. I would like to ask you also how can I proceed then in this case?

Comment: Either have a model for the calculations so that you store the data or have a link to a pdf route where you merge the parameters from when you calculated it.

Comment: Ok, I think the second option is better for a newbie as me :). Could you recommend me a tutorial or link where I can watch a example for this?

Comment: Your link to railscasts shows the pdf format link and merge is just a hash method, as the params are a hash.